# AngularJS and SparkJava. Never enter into .success() method and can't see server's response

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, client-server, spark-java

I'm just starting out with AngularJS and Client-Server programming overall. I have my AngularJS client and my Java server (made with SparkJava Framework).

This is a snippet of my controller's code:

```
var urlShortener = angular.module('urlShortener', []);

urlShortener.controller('shortenCtrl',
function($scope, $http){

    $scope.longUrl = "";

    $scope.shortening =
        function(longUrl){
            $http.get("http://localhost:4567/shortening", {params:{longUrl: longUrl}})
                .success(function(response){
                    alert("success");
                })
                .error(function(response){
                    alert("error");
                })
        }
 }
```

);

...and this my Maven Project's server code

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    get("/shortening", (request, response) -> {
        String longUrl = request.queryParams("longUrl");
        System.out.println(longUrl); //This works fine
        return "Yo";
    });
}
}
```

I'm just checking that all stuffs work well, but they don't. Every time I try to send some data from client to the server all works fine. But in the end, when the server send the response to the client, on my screen always appears the alert "error", so .success() it's never called.

Why? Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing with Google Chrome, please press F12, click 'Console' and execute the action that calls your controller's function. Probably you are facing the following error, isn't it ?

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

If that's the case, then do de following:

1: In your Java code, set the static file location (insert the line below as the first instruction for the main method):

```
externalStaticFileLocation("<complete-path-to-the-directory-in-which-your-html-page-is>");
```

2: In your JavaScript code, replace "http://localhost:4567/shortening" for "/shortening"

3: Instead of double-clicking your page file in order to open it in the browser, open your browser and access "http://localhost:4567/yourpagename.html"